# How to daisy chain php classes

Tags: php, class, object, models

I want to do this.

```
$ppl->tech->ceo->apple();
```

How would I make that work?

Comment: By writing the classes and using them maybe?

Comment: No how to make it so that they can daisy chain each other

Comment: Could you be more specific saying what you are trying to achieve and in which context. By doing that, it might be easier for the community to understand the problem. Try to explain what doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
class ppl {
  public $tech;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->tech = new tech();
  }
}

class tech {
  public $ceo;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->ceo = new ceo();
  }
}

class ceo {
  public function __construct(){

  }

  public function apple(){
    echo 'Hello.. I\'m apple.';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Daisy chaining can be achieved by returning a pointer to the object. It is often used to connect methods together like:

```
$db = new db();
$myquery = $db->Select('mytable')->Where('a > 1')->Execute();
```

Daisy chaining is not about  connecting properties with new classes;

Example:

```
class db 
{
  public function Select( $table )
  {
    // do stuff
    return $this;
  }

  public function Where( $Criterium )
  {
    // do stuff
    return $this;
  }

  public function Execute()
  {
    // do real work, return a result
  }
}
```